# Comparator and violating the contract of set

Tags: java, equals, comparator, contract

The JavaDoc of Comparator states that

> It is strongly recommended (though not required) that natural orderings be consistent with equals.

They also give an example of a "strange" behaviour when `(a.equals(b) && c.compare(a,b) != 0)`.

Now, can someone give me an example of a "strange" behavour in case `(!a.equals(b) && c.compare(a,b) == 0)`? This second case should occur more often than the first because it is easy to forget implementing `equals` for the compared type when implementing `Comparator`.  It's hard to come up with an example without knowing the implementation of, e.g., `TreeSet`.

(It's a longer story why this question is relevant to me.  And it's not a homework assignment)

Comment: If you read the documentation for `Set`, it says that if you have two equal objects, then only one (or neither) of them is stored in the set. This is not true if it's a TreeSet using a comparator that is not consistent with equals.

Comment: See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53901802/1441122

Comment: Thanks, Stuart Marks. Could you add your comment as regular answer, so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple demo. We have a class called `Strange` that implements `equals` and `hashCode` using case insensitive string comparisons but implements `compareTo` case sensitive.

```
class Strange implements Comparable<Strange> {

    final String s;

    public Strange(String s) {
        this.s = s;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        // Kind of equals - case insensitive.
        return (o instanceof Strange) && ((Strange) o).s.equalsIgnoreCase(s);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        // Consistent with equals.
        return s.toUpperCase().hashCode();
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Strange o) {
        // Exact ordering including case - inconsistent with equals.
        return s.compareTo(o.s);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return s;
    }

}

public void test() {
    Set<Strange> set1 = new HashSet<>();
    Set<Strange> set2 = new TreeSet<>();
    for (String s : new String[]{"Hello", "hello", "Everyone", "everyone"}) {
        Strange strange = new Strange(s);
        set1.add(strange);
        set2.add(strange);
    }
    System.out.println("Set1: " + set1);
    System.out.println("Set2: " + set2);
}
```

We get - as you probably expect:

```
Set1: [Hello, Everyone]
Set2: [Everyone, Hello, everyone, hello]
```

See how putting the strings in a `TreeSet` changes the outcome? This is because `TreeSet` uses `compareTo` while `HashSet` uses `equals` and `hashCode`. This can break things in many different (and most important **unexpected**) ways because you shouldn't have to know what kind of `Set` is being used behind the scenes.

This demonstrates `(a.equals(b) && a.compareTo(b) != 0)` gives strange results. It is easy to show that the opposite issue `(!a.equals(b) && a.compareTo(b) == 0)` also demonstrates strange results.

Answer (score 0):

JDK implementations of Collections rely on behavioural relationships like this. Another good example is HashSet, which relies on `equals()` and `hashCode()` agreeing.

By "strange" they mean "undefined" - there is no definition of how these classes will behave if they are working with classes that don't follow the rules. They may work perfectly, they may not. But you can not rely on them working properly if your element classes don't adhere to the behaviour described in their javadoc.

Comment: Of course, the behaviour is undefined.  But usually, there is a deterministic behaviour, depending on a concrete implementation (and sometimes on other factors, like VM version, operating system, ...) I was hoping for a concrete example of non-set behaviour in case of the given contract violation.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose the following API:

```
final class Foo {
    int bar;
    Foo(int bar) { this.bar = bar; }
    public int hashCode() {
        return bar;
    }
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        return o instanceof Foo && ((Foo)o).bar == bar;
    }
}

static Set<Foo> getSetOpaquely() {???}
```

I don't know where the Set comes from, just that I need to use it.

Suppose I assume the Set is like HashSet and defined in terms of `equals`.

> They also give an example of a "strange" behaviour when `(a.equals(b) && c.compare(a,b) != 0)`

Suppose I do

```
Set<Foo> mySet = getSetOpaquely();
mySet.add(new Foo(1));
System.out.println(mySet.add(new Foo(1));
```

Suppose my surprise when this prints `true` because it was a TreeSet with a Comparator

```
(lhs, rhs) -> lhs == rhs ? 0 : 1
```

> Now, can someone give me an example of a "strange" behavour in case `(!a.equals(b) && c.compare(a,b) == 0)`?

Suppose I do

```
Set<Foo> mySet = getSetOpaquely();
mySet.add(new Foo(102));
System.out.println(mySet.add(new Foo(12));
```

Suppose my surprise when this prints `false` because it was a TreeSet with a Comparator

```
(lhs, rhs) -> Integer.compare(lhs.bar % 10, rhs.bar % 10)
```

---

Now, there isn't an inherent problem with defining ordering that is inconsistent with `equals`. The point is that *a TreeSet might behave other than specified in the documentation for Set*.

This is [clearly documented](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html):

> [...] the `Set` interface is defined in terms of the equals operation, but a `TreeSet` instance performs all element comparisons using its `compareTo` (or `compare`) method, so two elements that are deemed equal by this method are, from the standpoint of the set, equal. **The behavior of a set *is* well-defined even if its ordering is inconsistent with equals; it just fails to obey the general contract of the `Set` interface.**

As long as the Comparator isn't hacky and you know that it's a TreeSet with a particular ordering, you won't be surprised. (If it's hacky like `(lhs, rhs) -> 1` you might be surprised.)