# consequence of compare() method of Comparator interface not consistent with equals() method

Tags: java, collections, equals, comparator, comparable

Say I have class `A`, which override the default `equals` method and implement `Comparable` interface (`Comparable` interface is said to be the natural ordering). To conform to good practice, the result returned by `equals` and `Comparable's compareTo` method should be consistent.

On some occasions, I want to compare instance of class `A` differently, so I implement `Comparator` interface (`Comparator` interface is said to be the unnatural ordering). So using `Comparable's compareTo` method and `Comparator's compare` method, the result would not be consistent.

If `equals` method and `Comparable's compareTo` interface is consistent, `Comparable's comparaTo` method and `Comparator's compare` method is not consistent, then `equals` method and `Comparator's compare` method would not be consistent as well.

So what are the consequences of `equals` method not consistent with `Comparator's compare` method, if there is any?

Comment: Use a `Comparator` instead - that way you don't have to care

Comment: @MadProgrammer could you please expand on that a little bit more?

Comment: It's recommended, but not strictly required that `Comparator.compare()` be consistent with `equals()`.

Comment: @shmosel will there be any consequences if `Comparator.compare()` is not consistent with `equals()`?

Comment: There may be, depending on how it's used. See the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) for details.

Comment: @Thor remember to overwrite ``hashcode()`` as well when you were overwriting ``equals()`` as well :)

Comment: @R.yan Thanks for the heads up! Definitely something I need to remember :)

Comment: `Comparator` allows you to define a "matching" algorithm which is independent of the `Object` itself, so you could have one which sorts `People` by name and one which sorts them by age and one which does both

Comment: If you're using a `Comparator` to implement a different order than the object's *natural order* (that is, its `Comparable.compareTo` method), you'd expect them to have different behaviors. Sure, they're not consistent with each other, but that's not a problem. Issues can arise if one of these comparison methods is not consistent with `equals`. For some examples of what can happen in this case, see my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53901802/1441122